# sqlldr generating ORA-00984: column not allowed here - while trying to add constant text

Tags: sql-loader

I need to load several similar csv files into work tables with the same format for onward processing but for some of the data I get 'ORA-00984: column not allowed here' errors.

I can't change the layout of the csv but the ordering of the columns in the work table and the format of the sqlldr control file are in my control.

What do I need to change to get sqlldr to load this data?

**EDIT: Solution: The following change to the .ctl file:
`col6_fixedchar constant "abc",` fixes the issue, interestingly sqlldr is quite happy with interpreting "3600" as a number.**

Below is a sample:

table:

```
create table test_sqlldr
(
    col1_date date,
    col2_char varchar2(15),
    col3_int number(5),
    col4_int number(5),
    col5_int number(5),
    -- fixed and dummy fields
    col6_fixedchar varchar2(15),
    col7_nullchar varchar2(20),
    col8_fixedint number(5)
);
```

csv:

```
cat /tmp/test_sqlldr.csv
2019-08-27 09:00:00,abcdefghi,3600,0,0
2019-08-27 09:00:00,jklmnopqr,3600,0,0
2019-08-27 09:00:00,stuvwxyza,3600,3598,3598
2019-08-27 09:00:00,bcdefghij,3600,0,0
```

ctl:

```
cat /tmp/test_sqlldr.ctl
load data infile '/tmp/test_sqlldr.csv'
insert into table test_sqlldr
fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"' TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
    col1_date timestamp 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss',
    col2_char,
    col3_int,
    col4_int,
    col5_int,
    col6_fixedchar "abc",
    col8_fixedint "3600"
)
```

This generates the following output:

```
/opt/oracle/product/112020_cl_64/cl/bin/sqlldr <db credentials> control='/tmp/test_sqlldr.ctl' ; cat test_sqlldr.log

SQL*Loader: Release 12.2.0.1.0 - Production on Wed Aug 28 10:26:00 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Path used:      Conventional
Commit point reached - logical record count 4

Table TEST_SQLLDR:
  0 Rows successfully loaded.

Check the log file:
  test_sqlldr.log
for more information about the load.

SQL*Loader: Release 12.2.0.1.0 - Production on Wed Aug 28 10:26:00 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Control File:   /tmp/test_sqlldr.ctl
Data File:      /tmp/test_sqlldr.csv
  Bad File:     /tmp/test_sqlldr.bad
  Discard File:  none specified

 (Allow all discards)

Number to load: ALL
Number to skip: 0
Errors allowed: 50
Bind array:     64 rows, maximum of 256000 bytes
Continuation:    none specified
Path used:      Conventional

Table TEST_SQLLDR, loaded from every logical record.
Insert option in effect for this table: INSERT
TRAILING NULLCOLS option in effect

   Column Name                  Position   Len  Term Encl Datatype
------------------------------ ---------- ----- ---- ---- ---------------------
COL1_DATE                           FIRST     *   ,  O(") DATETIME yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss
COL2_CHAR                            NEXT     *   ,  O(") CHARACTER
COL3_INT                             NEXT     *   ,  O(") CHARACTER
COL4_INT                             NEXT     *   ,  O(") CHARACTER
COL5_INT                             NEXT     *   ,  O(") CHARACTER
COL6_FIXEDCHAR                       NEXT     *   ,  O(") CHARACTER
    SQL string for column : "abc"
COL8_FIXEDINT                        NEXT     *   ,  O(") CHARACTER
    SQL string for column : "3600"

Record 1: Rejected - Error on table TEST_SQLLDR, column COL4_INT.
ORA-00984: column not allowed here

Record 2: Rejected - Error on table TEST_SQLLDR, column COL4_INT.
ORA-00984: column not allowed here

Record 3: Rejected - Error on table TEST_SQLLDR, column COL4_INT.
ORA-00984: column not allowed here

Record 4: Rejected - Error on table TEST_SQLLDR, column COL4_INT.
ORA-00984: column not allowed here


Table TEST_SQLLDR:
  0 Rows successfully loaded.
  4 Rows not loaded due to data errors.
  0 Rows not loaded because all WHEN clauses were failed.
  0 Rows not loaded because all fields were null.


Space allocated for bind array:                 115584 bytes(64 rows)
Read   buffer bytes: 1048576

Total logical records skipped:          0
Total logical records read:             4
Total logical records rejected:         4
Total logical records discarded:        0

Run began on Wed Aug 28 10:26:00 2019
Run ended on Wed Aug 28 10:26:00 2019

Elapsed time was:     00:00:00.14
CPU time was:         00:00:00.03
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: col6_fixedchar CONSTANT "abc"

Comment: I suspect you had it figured out before I posted my answer.